# Can I add indexes to the performance_schema in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

The performance_schema seems to have some [varying](http://dimitrik.free.fr/blog/archives/2013/07/mysql-performance-why-performance-schema-overhead.html) amounts of [performance impact](http://marcalff.blogspot.com/2011/06/performance-schema-overhead-tuning.html), and I'm curious what tools we have to mitigate the impact?

I see in mysql 8.x that the devs are looking into [setting up indexing](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-performance-schema-now-with-indexes/), is that potentially something we can manually add into the db ourselves?  If so, is there a resource we can use around adding indexes the PFS is likely to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not supported. You can't `ALTER TABLE` on the performance schema tables at all.

```
master [localhost] {root} (performance_schema) > select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.20-log |
+------------+

master [localhost] {root} (performance_schema) > alter table events_statements_summary_by_thread_by_event_name add primary key (thread_id, event_name);
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'performance_schema'

master [localhost] {root} (performance_schema) > show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Even if you could do it, adding indexes to the performance_schema prior to MySQL 8.0 wouldn't improve performance, it would make the overhead  worse.

The article you linked to said:

> Some readers might also have noted that the performance_schema tables are highly volatile, with data written to it continuously, while read only a few times, typically once in a while by a monitoring application. A table used in a workload which is write intensive with only a few reads is a red flag when it comes to add an index, as **the cost of maintaining the index is order of magnitudes higher that the benefits.**

The feature developed for MySQL 8.0 to simulate indexes just *pretends* to store persistent indexes. As the article says, they only report indexes to guide the optimizer on the best access pattern. There aren't really any indexes.